# Open Cv + Numpy + Python face detection for mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencart2.x

How can I make an OpenCV face detection for Python 2.7 on a Mac. I have tried many different codes but they all don't work. I am running them in terminal.

I get this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'
```

This seems to be right but I can't figure out what the error is. Here is the code for the face detection.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
faceCascade = 
cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) # set Width
cap.set(4,480) # set Height
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, -1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,     
        scaleFactor=1.2,
        minNeighbors=5,     
        minSize=(20, 20)
    )
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
         cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]  
    cv2.imshow('video',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # press 'ESC' to quit
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message indicates that the file path may be invalid, the program can't find **.xml** file. And  you may want to replace `'Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'` with a absolute path such as `'username/file/../cascade.xml'`

Comment: Thank you, is the file automatically installed for mac os or do I have to download something for it to work?

Comment: you need to download it from github: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades